# why is z = 4 +1j*3 recognized as a complex number, rather than a text value?

Tags: python

z = 4 +1j*3...I can imagine writing this for a text value or even a math formula assigned to z...why does python recognize this as  a complex number?

I am just trying to understand how python recoginizes z as a complex number.

Comment: Because this is the syntax used for complex numbers in Python. If you want to have a string then just put it in quotes.

Comment: @NotAName. Not exactly. `j` is a symbol (for example a variable). But `1j` is a complex number (pure imaginary one). Or any real number followed by `j`. It is part of the number syntax (or, to be more accurate, lexicography). Like the `e` (for power of 10 factor) or `.` (for decimal separator), or `_` (for digit grouping), etc. are.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the notation `z = 4 + 1j * 3` is recognized as a complex number because of the presence of the imaginary part `1j`.

Python uses the `j` or `J` suffix to denote the `imaginary unit`. When you perform operations involving complex numbers, the `j` or `J` suffix indicates that the number has both a `real` and an `imaginary` part.

In your example, `4 is the real part`, and `1j * 3 is the imaginary part`. The expression `1j * 3` evaluates to `3j`, which means `3 multiplied by the imaginary unit j`. So, `4 + 1j * 3` is equivalent to `4 + 3j`, representing a complex number with a `real part of 4` and an `imaginary part of 3`.

Answer (score 1):

`1j` or a number followed by `j` is considered as the `imag` part of a complex.
And for Python, if you want a text, you must use " or ' surround the contents.
Of course, you can consider the `4 + 1j*3` as a math formula assigned to z, so a real number `4` added to an imaginary number `3j`, equals `4+3j`, which was assigned to z, just the same as `z = 1 + 1` causes `z` equals to 2.